# Issue converting double-quotes from VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to convert below VB code into C#.Net but facing issue,while replacing `""""c`, with `""`

what is `""""c` in vb.

```
Dim strDeviceName As String = mo("Dependent").ToString.Replace(""""c, "")
```

Answer (score 2):

> what is """"c in vb.

`""""c` represents a double-quote character in VB. Inside a string literal, you have to write two double-quote characters to represent one double-quote. The first and last double-quotes delimitate the start and end of the string, and the `c` character indicates that it should be interpreted as a Character object and not a String object.

In C# the translation is:

```
string strDeviceName = mo("Dependent").ToString.Replace('"', "");
```

In C# a char is delimited by single-quotes so you don't have to escape double-quotes!